# Does a default_random_engine have a type?

Tags: c++

Well suppose i have a `default_random_engine` in C++ does the value he generates have a type?If so it is possible to do something like
    `sum = sum + generator;`
and suppose `sum` has a predefined type

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? It's very unclear what you're asking about. The [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) says that `default_random_engine` is implementation defined.

Comment: All the engines have a nested type `result_type` which is the type of the result. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> Does a default_random_engine have a type?

Yes. It is a typedef of one of the other engines.

§26.5.5

> Remark: The choice of engine type named by this typedef is implementation-defined. [ Note: The
>   implementation may select this type on the basis of performance, size, quality, or any combination of
>   such factors, so as to provide at least acceptable engine behavior for relatively casual, inexpert, and/or
>   lightweight use. Because different implementations may select different underlying engine types, code
>   that uses this typedef need not generate identical sequences across implementations. — end note ]

All of the random engines export the type `Engine::result_type` which is the return type of `Engine::result_type Engine::operator()`.

`result_type` is a typedef of the `UIntType` which is the first template argument.

e.g.:

```
std::mersenne_twister_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 
                         32, 624, 397, 31, 
                         0x9908b0df, 11, 
                         0xffffffff, 7, 
                         0x9d2c5680, 15, 
                         0xefc60000, 18, 1812433253>
```

In which the return type of `operator()` is `std::uint_fast32_t`.

Comment: While I concur with the facts of this answer, it would seem the OP may have asked a different question than that answered here (whether they realize it or not). Specifically, "in C++ does the value *he generates* have a type" suggests confusion of the type of data generated, not the type of the generator itself. Frankly, I'm not convinced the OP even knows what was asked.

Comment: @WhozCraig ah yes, now I re-read the question I see what you're saying.

Comment: Exactly. Solid answer, to be sure, but just not sure if it answers the OP's question (whatever that was =P).

Comment: @WhozCraig updated. hopefully that covers everything.